# how to have button in every value

Tags: php, mysql

> i tried this code. but there are only one x button and it delete only the first value i want every
>   value that has been bold have x button.and  what should i do ? . the
>   picture show below the example. Thankyou in advance,

[image]

```
if ($specializations = selected_specializations()) {

    $groupped_spec = [];
    $groupped_pcon = [];
    foreach ($specializations as $specialization) {
        $spec  = $specialization["Specialization"];

        $groupped_pcon[$spec][] = $specialization["PossibleCondition"];
        $groupped_spec[$spec][] = array_only($specialization, ['id', 'Specialization', 'Specialization1', 'Specialization2']);
    }

    foreach ($groupped_spec as $Specialization => $groupped_specializations) {
        $PossibleCondition = implode("<br />", array_unique($groupped_pcon[$Specialization]));

        echo "      <b>{$PossibleCondition}</b><br />\n";

        foreach (array_unique_arrays($groupped_specializations, ['id']) as $specialization) {
            $id    = $specialization["id"];
            $spec  = $specialization["Specialization"];
            $spec1 = $specialization["Specialization1"];
            $spec2 = $specialization["Specialization2"];

            ?>
            <button class="btn btn-link" name="delete_spec" aria-label="Left Align" data-id="<?php print $id;?>">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
            </button>
<ul>
            <a href="hgapp.php?doc=<?php echo $spec  ?>"><u><?php echo $spec  ?></u></a>
            <a href="hgapp.php?doc=<?php echo $spec1 ?>"><u><?php echo $spec1 ?></u></a>
            <a href="hgapp.php?doc=<?php echo $spec2 ?>"><u><?php echo $spec2 ?></u></a>
            </ul>
            <?php
        }

?>


<?php

        }

    }
?>

</div>

<script type="template" id="specialization_group_template">
    <b>{PossibleCondition}</b><br />{specializations}<br />

</script>


<script type="template" id="specialization_template">
    <button name="delete_spec"class="btn btn-link" aria-label="Left Align" data-id="{id}">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>
<ul>
    <a href="hgapp.php?doc={Specialization}"><u>{Specialization}</u></a>
    <a href="hgapp.php?doc={Specialization1}"><u>{Specialization1}</u></a><br>
    <a href="hgapp.php?doc={Specialization2}"><u>{Specialization2}</u></a>
    </ul>
</script>
```

Comment: relevance to the mysqli tag is?

Comment: ididnt include but i use mysqli tag in my function

Comment: I removed the tag for it. You can put it back in once you've added the relevant code for mysql(i).

Comment: you also have a syntax error here `if ($specializations = selected_specializations())` - You're doing an assignment rather than a comparison. T

Comment: this `if ($specializations == selected_specializations())` with 2 equals signs.

Comment: wheres the code that shows the function of the delete button?

Comment: function track_specs() {
  $('button[name="delete_spec"]').each(function() { 
this.onclick = null; 
$(this).click(function () { 
delete_specs($(this).data("id")); 
return false; 
}); 
});
 }

Comment: show the code for `function delete_specs()`

Comment: that was the ajax function

Answer (score -1):

You have one result and in that result you have 3 specs that you list and you did put only one button.

Check this part of your code I added buttons per spec since you want a button per spec. You need to define the rest by your self. Like how the button will perform the deletion and so on. What data you need to pass to be able to do that. etc..

```
    foreach (array_unique_arrays($groupped_specializations, ['id']) as $specialization) {
        $id    = $specialization["id"];
        $spec  = $specialization["Specialization"];
        $spec1 = $specialization["Specialization1"];
        $spec2 = $specialization["Specialization2"];

        ?>
       <ul>
        <a href="hgapp.php?doc=<?php echo $spec  ?>"><u><?php echo $spec  ?>
        </u></a>
          <button class="btn btn-link" name="delete_spec" aria-label="Left Align" data-id="<?php print $id;?>">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </button>

        <a href="hgapp.php?doc=<?php echo $spec1 ?>"><u><?php echo $spec1 ?>    
        </u></a>
          <button class="btn btn-link" name="delete_spec" aria-label="Left Align" data-id="<?php print $id;?>">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="hgapp.php?doc=<?php echo $spec2 ?>"><u><?php echo $spec2 ?>
        </u></a>
          <button class="btn btn-link" name="delete_spec" aria-label="Left Align" data-id="<?php print $id;?>">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </button>
        </ul>
        <?php
    }
```

Comment: Really? Are you sure that this is wrong? Did you try it on your page? Can you send a test php page which you used this addition? Can you send the array that you are using for all those for eachs? I assume you are the one who gave the downvote!

Comment: Then we have a troll who just clicks on downvote buttons to have fun!

Comment: Im your troll. I downed you because OP states they want all values deleted when one button is pressed, not adding extra buttons.

Comment: Read the question carefully my friend! 

 i want every value that has been bold have x button.and what should i do ?

Comment: ha! I trolled myself then. Their english sucks.

Comment: Yep, but still understandable.